# Need to show a turning cube on top of a view

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, opengl-es

I have a view with an image that is semi transparent on top of my app, and I am going to need to display a 3D cube (or even a 3D look alike cube - made of 3 polygons) on that view.
Each face of the cube is touchable, and should identify once touched. ie, fire an event with it's ID or each fire it's own event, Which in turn will turn the cube...
How can I accomplish that ?

I'll try to visualize what I am after:

**So, to go from this shown cube...**
[image]

**After touching the red face**
[image]

This code simply shows a simple touchable button firing an event, which is all I have now

```
@implementation cubeView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Label.png"]];
        // For RETINA DISPLAY create an image named Label@2x.png and make it twice big in x and in y
        [self addSubview:view];
        UILabel * lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,100,30)];
        [lbl setText:@"Hello"];
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self addSubview:lbl];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**the view controller**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *container = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 400, 200)]  
autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:container];
    container.alpha = 0.2;
    UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    b.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 201, 98);
    cubeView *cb = [[[SS alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 201, 98)] autorelease];
    [b setImage:[self imageWithView:cb] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [container addSubview:b];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to what exactly your question is, but if you want to figure out a way to rotate the cube,you'll need some coordinates which specify its edges and vertices. i have a rotating cube for my project, which uses rotation matrices to find the final coordinates of it. you need to feed in the angle through which you have to rotate.to 'turn' it, you need to go through the angle in steps of whatever speed/precision you like and keep a specific pause between successive calls of the 'view' cube function so that it rotates gradually. showing the cube works in matlab using the 'patch' command.maybe there's some similar function in ios dev.

Comment: I am aware that using openGL 3D may be overkill, and I am thinking more of the polygons approach, but I am looking for some code to implement on the semi transparent view shown above.